# Difference between the distinct entries and non distinct entries of a column

Tags: mysql

Find the difference between the total number of records in **CITY** column of table and the number of distinct **CITY** records in the table.

*City_table*:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| ID | NUMBER |
| CITY | VARCHAR |
| STATE | VARCHAR |
| LAT_N | NUMBER |
| LONG_W | NUMBER |

```
select count(*) 
    from (select CITY 
          FROM STATION NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
                               FROM STATION))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier:

```
SELECT count(city), count(distinct city)
FROM station
```

You just need to count all the occurrencies of city (`count(city)`) and count the distinct values (`count(distinct city)`)